# I try to prove the theorem about the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ converges then sequence $a_{n}$ converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^N(a_{n+1}-a_n)=a_N-a_1$$

Answer (score 1):

I study math in French so I'm not sure I'll be choosing the "perfect" words and terms. Try to prove the contrapositive: If the sequence doesn't converge then the series doesn't converge. If the sequence doesn't converge then $a(n+1)-a(n)$ does not converge to zero, and if a sequence doesn't converge to zero then the series wont converge at all.

Comment: The English word is "Contrapositive".

Comment: I also recommend learning some [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

If the series converges, in particular $\Sigma _n^m (a_{i+1}-a_i )= |a_{m}-a_n| \longrightarrow 0$, which is to say that the series is Cauchy. Any Cauchy in a complete space is convergent.